# How to execute function in parent class using 'exec' in child class?

Tags: python, exec, eval

I want to run code from **superclass** using **exec** or **eval** but how? 
This is parent class:

```py
class A():
    def f1(self):
        print("hello")
```

This is child class:

```py
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.funtion='super().'+func
        print(self.funtion)
        exec(self.funtion)

b=B('f1()')
```

**Result**

```py
super().f1()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-bdf8f567ee6e> in <module>
----> 1 b=B('f1()')

<ipython-input-43-3d6eddb1536b> in __init__(self, func)
      3         self.funtion='super().'+func
      4         print(self.funtion)
----> 5         exec(self.funtion)

<string> in <module>

RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `exec` or `eval`?

Comment: I need a class like this.
```python
c = Condition(data=data,func='median',separate_negative = True)
```
and func are defined in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the method is defined in the parent class (and isn’t overrided by the child class), use `getattr`:

```
class A:
    def median(self):
        return ...

class Condition(A):
    def __init__(self, data, func, separate_negative):
        self.data = data
        self.func = getattr(self, func)
        self.separate_negative = separate_negative
```

Then to use it, just call `self.func()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `super()` in `getaddr()` -

```
class A():
    def f1(self):
        return "hello"
        #print("hello")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.function=getattr(super(), func)
        self.value = self.function()
        print(self.value)

b=B('f1')
```

It works just fine.

```
$./pysuperclass.py
hello
```

And make sure that your `f1()` returns rather than printing, printing is not stored in a variable.